# Hosting React app with Gitlab pages on root domain

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gitlab

I have a React app, and I want to deploy it on Gitlab pages.

I could successfully deploy it to: `https://company.gitlab.com/projectname`

but I am unable to deploy it on: `https://company.gitlab.com/`, I always get a 404

Here is my configuration:

.gitlab_ci.yml

```
# Using the node alpine image to build the React app
image: node:alpine

# Announce the URL as per CRA docs
# https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration
variables:
  PUBLIC_URL: /
# Cache node modules - speeds up future builds
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules

# Name the stages involved in the pipeline
stages:
- deploy

# Job name for gitlab to recognise this results in assets for Gitlab Pages
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#gitlab-pages-requirements
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install # Install all dependencies
    - npm run build --prod # Build for prod
    - cp public/index.html public/404.html # Not necessary, but helps with https://medium.com/@pshrmn/demystifying-single-page-applications-3068d0555d46
    - mv public _public # CRA and gitlab pages both use the public folder. Only do this in a build pipeline.
    - mv build public # Move build files to public dir for Gitlab Pages
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public # The built files for Gitlab Pages to serve
  only:
    - master # Only run on master branch
```

In App.js, I added `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import browserHistory from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";
import {HomeLayoutFr, HomeLayoutEn, MentionsLayout} from "./layout.js";
const supportsHistory = "pushState" in window.history;
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} forceRefresh={!supportsHistory}>
                <div className="main">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route history={browserHistory} path="/mentions">
                            <MentionsLayout />
                        </Route>
                        <Route history={browserHistory} path="/en">
                            <HomeLayoutEn />
                        </Route>
                        <Route history={browserHistory} exact path="/">
                            <HomeLayoutFr />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

When I use a /project at the end of the url, I had to add:

```
variables:
  PUBLIC_URL: /projectname
```

in `.gitlab_ci.yml`

I also had to add:

```
"homepage": "https://company.gitlab.io/projectname",
```

in `package.json`

Any idea how to get out of the 404 error ???

Answer (score 2):

In order to deploy to *company.gitlab.io* your project`s name actually has to be *company.gitlab.io*
This can feel unintuitive, but there is no way around it.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#user-and-group-websites